# Python: time/platform independent fast hash for big sets of pairs of ints

Tags: python, hash

I would like to get a time and platform independent hash function for big sets of pairs of integers in Python, which is also fast and has (almost certainly) no collision. (Hm, what else do you want a hash to be - but anyway... .)

What I have so far is to use `hashlib.md5` on the string representation of the sorted list:

```
> my_set = set([(1,2),(0,3),(1,3)]) # the input set, size 1...10^6

> import hashlib
> def MyHash(my_set):
>     my_lst = sorted(my_set)
>     my_str = str(my_lst)
>     return hashlib.md5(my_str).hexdigest()
```

`my_set` contains between 1 and 10^5 pairs, and each `int` is between 0 and 10^6. In total, I have about 10^8 such sets on which the hash should be almost certainly unique.

> Does this sound reasonable, or is there a better way of doing it?

On my example set with 10^6 pairs in the list, this takes about `2.5sec`, so improvements on the time might be good, if possible. Almost all of the time is spend computing the string of the sorted list, so a big part of the question is

> Is the string of a sorted list of tuples of integers in python stable among versions and platforms? Is there a better/faster way of obtaining a stable string representation?

Comment: For starters MD5 is generally faster than SHA512. So the question becomes, just how difficult do you want it to be to generate collisions? They won't occur by accident with MD5, but collisions are known, does that rule it out? If so then I think you have no choice but to use a solid cryptographic hash, and pay the time cost for it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- I guess you are right. But I checked, and the speed to compute the actually hash is not really relevant here. Almost all of the time is spent producing the string of the sorted list.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I updated the question to use MD5 and added another sub-question.

Comment: If you're willing to write C code and can guarantee that each value is <= 10^6, then writing the sorted pairs of integers as a sequence of fixed-width binary values, 3 or 4 bytes each, could be faster than calling `str`. Since it's fixed width you don't need any separators and can also predict the total size in advance, saving some time. The reason I say "willing to write C code" is that as soon as you write a loop in Python you risk slowing the whole thing down, but it's probably worth at least testing the performance of a Python version.